# Rewrite url name using with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have sample website name is `example.com/customer/?loc=dashboard`, this website is used PHP coding. I need to change last name `?loc=dashboard` to `dashboard`. That means I want the result website name is `mydomain.com/customer/dashboard`

I have added a file called `.htaccess` in my root folder, and add something like this, but it cannot work:

```html
ReWriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/dashboard /?loc=dashboard [L]
```

I have refer this website `https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204643270/.htaccess-rewrite-rules` to do. But cannot work. Hope someone can guide me on how to solve this problem. Thanks.

**Updated - 1**

Using @RavinderSingh13 method result:

[image]

Before `?loc=dashboard` result:

[image]

**Updated 12/11/2021 09:19:00**

**Rewrite rules**

```html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com\.my [OR,NC] 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com.my/$1 [R,L]


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com\.my [OR,NC] 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mydomain.com.my/$1 [R,L]

##External redirect to /customer/dashboard url rules here.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/customer/?\?loc=(\S+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^  /customer/%1? [R=301,L]

##Internal rewrite rules to get it served by index.php file.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^customer/(.*)/?$ index.php?parameter=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

**Update - 2**

```html
everyoneknows.come.my/.htaccess
everyoneknows.come.my/index.php
everyoneknows.come.my/customer
everyoneknows.come.my/customer/index.php
everyoneknows.come.my/customer/account/dashboard.php
```

So that, in my php code, I use `?loc=` replace `account`, then become everyoneknows.come.my/customer/?loc=dashboard

**Update -3**

I am using this method to get `?loc`:

```html
if (isset($_GET['loc'])) {
    if (file_exists('account/' . $_GET['loc'] . '.php')) {
        // if ($module_user_permission['view'] == 1) {
            include_once 'account/' . $_GET['loc'] . '.php';
        // } else {
            // if ($_GET['loc'] != 'home') {
                // include_once 'app/access_denied.php';
            // } else {
                // include_once 'account/dashboard.php';
            // }
        // }
    } else {
        include_once 'account/dashboard.php';
    }
} else {
    include_once 'account/dashboard' . (isset($_GET['system']) ? "_" . $_GET['system'] : "") . '.php';
}
```

Comment: 1. When configure in .htaccess, the path RewriteRule matches against, never starts with a leading slash, that has been stripped off at this point already.

Comment: 2. You say you placed this in the root, so the path you want to match should be `customer/dashboard`, not just `dashboard`. And same for the substitution URL.

Comment: @CBroe So must write like this `RewriteRule ^customer/dashboard /?loc=dashboard [L]`, right?

Comment: Do you want to rewrite _to_ `mydomain.com/?loc=dashboard` ...?

Comment: No. I want rewrite like this `mydomain.com/customer/dashboard` or `mydomain.com/customer/dashboard/`

Comment: @CBroe Is possible rewrite like this URL?

Comment: Of course it "is possible" ... My hint was supposed to make you specify the _correct_ paths, and not just parts of them.

Comment: @CBroe I write like this `RewriteRule ^/dashboard /customer/?loc=dashboard [L]` , also cannot change path

Comment: Again: If your .htaccess is located on the root level, then the requested URL path is _not_ just `/dashboard`. And that the leading slash is wrong there in any case, is the very first thing I told you.

Comment: @FattSky, so you mean you are hitting link `mydomain.com/customer/?loc=dashboard` and want it to redirect it to `mydomain.com/customer/dashboard`(change in browser)? Please confirm on this one. If yes then from which file new link `mydomain.com/customer/dashboard` should be served in backend? Is it `index.php` file?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 yes. redirect to `mydomain.com/customer/dashboard`

Comment: @FattSky, ok then from which file new link mydomain.com/customer/dashboard should be served in backend? Is it `index.php` file?

Comment: Yes. Is index.php

Comment: A 500 error is a very generic "something went wrong" type of error.  It seems likely to be a syntax error in your .htaccess file.   The way to diagnose it is to look in your web server's error_log file which will have more information about exactly what the error is.

Answer (score 2):

With your shown attempts, samples; please try following htaccess rules file. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

Make sure your htaccess rules file is present alongside with `customer` folder(not inside it). In 2nd rewrite rule I have added `parameter` to get it pass to `index.php` file you can set it as per your requirement.

```
RewriteEngine ON
##Applying www by external redirect rules here...
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com\.my [NC] 
RewriteCond HTTPS off
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ https://www.example.com.my/$1 [R,L]

##External redirect to /customer/dashboard url rules here.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/customer/?\?loc=(\S+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^  /customer/%1? [R=301,L]

##Internal rewrite rules to get it served by dashboard.php file.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^customer/(.*)/?$ customer/account/dashboard.php?parameter=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239158/discussion-on-answer-by-ravindersingh13-rewrite-url-name-using-with-htaccess).